# tomcat welcome file is not sitting in its relative path

Tags: java, html, tomcat7

I have an application that have in the root 2 folders 
I want the welcome file to be under the folder

> dist/index.html
>   So i add my welcome file like this :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>dist/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

project looks like this 

    application
       -dist/index.html
       -app/index.html
```

what happen is that it works fine but all the scripts that are in the html file are not found 
and i get 404 for them. 
when i directly go to the folder without using the welcome it will load just fine application/dist/index.html
Any idea ?

Comment: what exactly you mean by "direct go to the folder" ? Also present your directory structure for more clarity

Comment: I still did not get what is meant by "direct go to the folder".

Comment: How are you scripts referenced? Can you post the relevant part of dist/index.html? Note that welcome file is served from the context root `http://host:port/context/` But if you access directly, then it's from `http://host:port/context/dist/index.html`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers , it turns out the app should be out side the server if you want to make use of the context tag , so i tried another approach and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers , it turns out the app should be out side the server if you want to make use of the context tag , so i tried another approach and it worked